# Why encryption in codeigniter working in local server but not on the server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I used the below code in my local `wamp` server and everything is perfect.

```
$this->encryption->encode($result['wo_id']);
```

But the same code is showing error when uploading to the web server online. Why?

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: ERROR - 2015-03-25 09:52:59 --> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 571 of 578 bytes D:\Program Files\wamp\www\ems\app\models\general_model.php 779

Comment: Path in error message is telling that error is in localhost. You said everything in local was ok?

Comment: Tpojka yes but i didn't get this error message when i run in local and i solved it by enabling php extension php_mcrypt. (Since PHP version of my server is old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP version of my server was old. I enabled PHP extension **php_mcrypt** from

> ***WAMP icon -> PHP ->PHP extensions -> php_mcrypt***

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the Mcrypt library on your server for the Codeigniter encryption library to work properly.

If you have root access to your server and are using something like Ubuntu/Debian doing this should be as easy as `sudo apt-get install mcrypt`.

Then just restart your server and you should find that everything works.

Comment: But I'm using windows. can you tell me what should i do to install Mcrypt library

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do this on Windows, but it looks like you've figured it out below :)